# Inadequate Encryption Strength

Tags: java, spring-security

Veracode has reported a vulnerability in RSAkeyHelper. The key size specified for this algorithm is not large enough to protect it from brute force attacks. As per the remediation comments, key size should be 2048 bit.  Could you provide some guidance on fixing or mitigating this vulnerability?

Jar: spring-security-rsa-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar
File: RSAKeyHelper.java

```
static KeyPair generateKeyPair() {
    try {
        final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(1024);
        return keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace 1024 with 2048?

Comment: You should report it as a bug if not already done so.

Answer (score 0):

The line

`keygen.initialize(1024);`

is setting the keysize. Changing 1024 to 2048 or greater, should put you in compliance.